# Subtracting a function from data to flatten it

Tags: python, numpy

So I have this dataset that comes out like this:
[image]

but I would like to manipulate it so that the little spikes on the end come out flattened like this but preferably with the wings closer to where they fit at the end of the two main lobes:

[image]

So far I've tried two different methods. First I used the built in np.polyfit function like

```
X = xave[1:20]
Y = sum[1:20]
fit = np.polyfit(X, Y, 1)
linear_baseline = np.poly1d(fit) 
sum = sum - linear_baseline(xave)
```

but that only works on one side and when I tried something a bit more hands on, like:

```
1 = -1 * np.polyfit(xave[0:20], sum[0:20], 1)[0]
2 = -1 * np.polyfit(xave[int(l1/2)-20:int(l1/2)+20], sum[int(l2/2)-20:int(l2/2)+20], 1)[0]
3 = -1 * np.polyfit(xave[l1-20:l1],   sum[l2-20:l2], 1)[0]
sum[0:20] =  sum[0:20] +1 * np.asarray(xave[0:20])
sum[int(l2/2)-20:int(l2/2)+20] =  sum[int(l2/2)-20:int(l2/2)+20] +2 * np.asarray(xave[int(l1/2)-20:int(l1/2)+20])
sum[l2-20:l2]   =  sum[l2-20:l2] +3 * np.asarray(xave[l1-20:l1])
```

I get the ends flattened but shifted up dramatically. Is there any way to solve this issue?

Comment: Do you understand what you're asking?  "I need to manipulate my actual result set so it looks like another result set".  Is that ethical?  If the Y axes are different, then why should your results look like that?  If there's a formula to transform resistivity into voltage, then by all means run it through that formula, but what you're asking seems wrong.

Comment: If it's just a matter of modelling this as a combination of a low-frequency system and high-frequency system I don't see any ethical issues (so long as that's reflected in any analytic report). Can you post sample data?

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned that the second plot up there has already been manipulated with the second piece of code I posted. I'm not trying to necessarily make the two plots look exactly alike but I just flatten out the data at the ends so that we can compare a measurement to a similar measurement taken at a different temperature.

Comment: Do a weighted linear fit that de-emphasizes the lobe section. But I can't show how to do this without data.

Comment: Sure thing! how should I include data since the files are highkey kinda big